# Hadoop mapreduce use old jar file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I updated `hive-common-0.11.0.1.3.0.0-0481.jar`. But my hive job, that executed from oozie, using old jar from path `C:/Hadoop/hdfs/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/25738279951503263_835947396_1968098702/10.0.2.15/user/hadoop/share/lib/hive/hive-common-0.11.0.1.3.0.0-0481.jar`.

How to make hadoop update disk cache?

Comment: Problem solved. Jars was stored in hdfs, on job running they are extracted from hdfs. We need to remove replaced jar from hdfs.